# Parse custom string into XML doc with XmlService

Tags: javascript, xml, google-apps-script

I continue to receive the same error during the process of using the XmlService.parse() on a custom string I'm using to send as a POST to a web service (Advise or suggestions in accomplishing this would be greatly appreciated also).
I will include the code for reference. I made an element in the string of type List which is whats most puzzling (Error on line 1: Open quote is expected for attribute "Name" associated with an element type "List". (line 67, file "Code")). Thanks!

```
    function createXml() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID"),
    activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
    refDatasrc = ss.getSheetByName("Student"),
    refDataRange = refDatasrc.getDataRange(),
    values = refDataRange.getValues();
  var xmlst = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><List Name=GS Test" Department="First Department"><Columns><Rows>';

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (i < 1) {
      var xmlCol = '<c>' + values[0][0] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][1] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][2] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][3] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][4] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][5] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][6] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][7] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][8] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][9] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][10] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][11] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][12] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][13] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][14] + '</c></Columns><Rows>';
      xmlst += xmlCol;
    } else {
      var xmlRows = '<r><v>' + values[i][0] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][1] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][2] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][3] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][4] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][5] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][6] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][7] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][8] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][9] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][10] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][11] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][12] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][13] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][14] + '</v></r>';
      xmlst += xmlRows;
    }
  }
  xmlst += '</Rows></List>';
  Logger.log(xmlst + '\n\n\n\n');
  var document = XmlService.parse(xmlst);
  var output = XmlService.getCompactFormat().format(document);
  Logger.log(output);
  //   var document = XmlService.createDocument(root);
  //   var xml = XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(document);
  //   Logger.log('\n\n\n\n' + xml);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about following modification?

#### Modification points :

1. For `var xmlst = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><List Name=GS Test" Department="First Department"><Columns><Rows>';`, please modify from `Name=GS Test"` to `Name="GS Test"`. This is the reason for the error.
2. In your script, the element types are `<List><Columns><Rows></Columns><Rows></Rows></List>` For this, please modify from `<List><Columns><Rows></Columns><Rows></Rows></List>` to `<List><Columns></Columns><Rows></Rows></List>`.

#### Modified script :

```
function createXml() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID"),
    activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
    refDatasrc = ss.getSheetByName("Student"),
    refDataRange = refDatasrc.getDataRange(),
    values = refDataRange.getValues();
  var xmlst = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><List Name="GS Test" Department="First Department"><Columns>';

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (i < 1) {
      var xmlCol = '<c>' + values[0][0] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][1] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][2] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][3] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][4] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][5] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][6] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][7] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][8] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][9] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][10] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][11] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][12] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][13] + '</c>' +
        '<c>' + values[0][14] + '</c></Columns><Rows>';
      xmlst += xmlCol;
    } else {
      var xmlRows = '<r><v>' + values[i][0] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][1] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][2] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][3] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][4] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][5] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][6] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][7] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][8] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][9] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][10] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][11] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][12] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][13] + '</v>' +
        '<v>' + values[i][14] + '</v></r>';
      xmlst += xmlRows;
    }
  }
  xmlst += '</Rows></List>';
  Logger.log(xmlst + '\n\n\n\n');
  var document = XmlService.parse(xmlst);
  var output = XmlService.getCompactFormat().format(document);
  Logger.log(output);
  //   var document = XmlService.createDocument(root);
  //   var xml = XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(document);
  //   Logger.log('\n\n\n\n' + xml);
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfectly! Now I'm looking to use this object and send it with POST. If you have any suggestions on accomplishing this It would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @M.Chavez Welcome. Thank you, too. You can send data with POST method using ``UrlFetchApp.fetch()``. The detail information is [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app).